# Clean a JSON in a PostGreSQL request

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a SQL request that is almost perfect (for what I want to do):

```
WITH liste_fichiers_joints AS (
    SELECT
        id_dans_table,
        ARRAY_AGG (row_to_json(f)) ids_fichier
    FROM
        fichiers_joints fj
    LEFT JOIN fichiers f ON f.id = fj.id_fichier
    WHERE
        nom_table = 'taches'
    GROUP BY
        id_dans_table
    )
SELECT t.id, t.nom, lfj.ids_fichier
FROM taches t
JOIN liste_fichiers_joints lfj ON lfj.id_dans_table = t.id
```

As you may have guessed, I'd like to get in the same request getting all the tasks: the id of a task, the name of the task but also in an array all the ids and names of the attached files if there are any.

The result is nearly what I want, but the last column displays this:

```
{"{\"uuid\":\"fd809b1f-6849-4322-a654-67f70c46a435\",\"nom\":\"test.png\",\"date\":\"2020-11-17T01:21:24.223354\",\"status\":\"TMP\",\"id\":185}"}
```

I'd like to remove the `uuid` and `status` parts, I tried some subrequests, up to no avail.
Also, I'd like to remove the backslashes `\`, because otherwise it will be complicated to use this column as a JSON in my Javascript.

Does anybody has a clue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json[b]_build_object()` instead of `row_to_json[b]()`: it accepts a list of key/value pairs, so you have fine-grained control about what is going into your objects.

Also, you most likely want a JSON array, rather than a Postgres array of JSON objects.

I would recommend changing this:

```
ARRAY_AGG (row_to_json(f)) ids_fichier
```

To:

```
jsonb_agg(
    jsonb_build_object('nom', f.nom, 'date', f.date, 'id', f.id)
) as ids_fichier
```

Comment: And that is perfectly workinng. Thanks, I didn't know this "jsonb_agg" function, it will become very handy.
Have a nice day :)